# is it possible to have sub menus in the sliding menu?

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, slidingmenu, drawerlayout

Hi i have implemented a Android sliding menu using navigation drawer with help of WWW.androidhive.info tutorial.

now my question is , is it possible to have sub menus in the sliding menu?

i mean for example assume i have four options in sliding menu "Facebook","twitter","watsup","android".  and my question is , if i press on Facebook a sub menu must come in down, with in that i must have some other options , like "photos","places" etc..

when i click on Facebook a drop down menu must appear by pushing down the other items(twitter,watsup,android) in the sliding menu.

(i want sub menu should be shown in the same sliding menu. not in a new sliding menu)

Comment: @Siddharth Lele: have already checked that one, and that's not helpful for me. There a new sliding menu is opening but i want sub menu to be opened in the same sliding menu. now i am working on expandable listview as suggested by Shivam Verma.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `ExpandableListView` instead of `ListView` in the navigation drawer.

Comment: Please include a short explanation of why this solves the question and what the difference between these two classes is.

Comment: @TimBodeit : if u use listview you cant have sub menus in it. but in expantablelistview we can have.

Comment: Then please include that in your answer. You can use the edit function to add additional information.

Comment: i have included @TimBodeit

Comment: Hi i have successfully implemented expandablelistview on slidingmenu :) Thanks to Shivam Veer for his idea :) and also tanx to SathMK :)

Answer (score 3):

Why not use the expandable list views in the drawer layout : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.html

Comment: is it possible to use expandablelistview in slidermenu? have u tried before ?